# Как получить данные из сервера node.js на клиент

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

У меня есть сервер на node.js с использованием Express. И есть скрипт на JavaScript и jQuery. Так вот, как получить данные из сервера на клиент.

Comment: какие данные вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я хочу получить строку

Comment: На клиенте сделать запрос на сервер, на сервере обработать этот запрос и вернуть данные. В каком именно месте возникают затруднения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код сервера (отвечал на другой ваш вопрос), немного расширенный:

#### `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const mustache = require('consolidate').mustache
const app = express()

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.engine('html', mustache)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/client', (req, res) => res.render('test'))

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  let name = req.query.name
  res.send({text: 'Your name is ' + name})
})


app.listen(3000)
```

Вот код на клиенте:

#### `views/test.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="input-name" name="input-name">
  <div id="output"></div>
  <button onclick="test()">Test</button>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function test() {
    let input = $('#input-name')
    let nameFromInput = input.val()
    let params = {
      name: nameFromInput
    }
    $.get('/test', params, function(serverResponse) {
      let textFromServerResponse = serverResponse.text
      let outputDiv = $('#output')

      outputDiv.text(textFromServerResponse)
    })
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Структура проекта:

```
project
- package.json
— app.js
— views
— — test.html
```

По адресу `http://localhost:3000/client` будет доступна простенькая страничка c полем ввода и кнопкой. По нажатию на кнопку на сервер отправится запрос с содержимым поля ввода, там он обработается и отдаст ответ клиенту с уже другой строкой, которая потом отобразится чуть ниже поля ввода.